# Parse and Redirect to uri in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Example that could be turned into a button to view user's public ftp where initial page is "http://user.school.edu/":

```
javascript:(function( {
   var h,i,t;
   h=window.location.hostname;i=h.IndexOf('.school.edu');t=h.substring(0,i);
   window.location.assign("ftp://ftp.school.edu/public/"+t
});
```

Help me refine this idea, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can also be written in "one line" using regular expression:

```
window.location = window.location.hostname.replace(
    /^(.*)\.school\.edu$/,
    "ftp://ftp.school.edu/public/$1"
);
```

I believe in this case regular expression expresses the intent more clearly than using indexOf and string slicing, though tastes may vary.

Comment: But then, regular expressions for this task is a bit overkill.

Comment: Regex was not the way I was going, but it does what I want in a geeky-elegant kind of way. I also like that it maintains the replace method so that history is intact.  I'm going to run with this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
  var h = window.location.hostname;
  window.location = 'ftp://ftp.school.edu/public/' + h.substring(0, h.indexOf('.'));
}());
```

- In JS, you can merge declaration and definition. The compiler takes care of splitting them to declaration and definition during compile.
- Since `indexOf` returns the first occurrence of a string, you can use the first dot (`.`) instead of `.school.edu`. Both will return the same value, but using a single dot is shorter.
- You can change the browser location by assigning a url to `window.location` than using `assign()`. Although using `assign()` might be a more proper way to do it, changing the value of `window.location` is still shorter
- I JS, single and double quotes don't matter. However, single quotes look cleaner.
- I also prefer the comma-separated `var` notation since it will save you retyping `var` every time. However, don't ever forget the commas.

Comment: `Both will return the same value` It won't, if you have address like `http://foo.bar.school.edu/`

Comment: @LieRyan look at the OP's post. The url pattern given was `user.school.edu` and nothing more.

Comment: The comma-separated approach does look much cleaner.